# How can I set constant in Model CharField and used in Form

Tags: python, django

I am new for Python and Django, and now I try to use constant such as max_length_value for Model and want to be re-used in the Form, but get exception when debug. I googled and try the property usage, but failed.
code list like below
models.py

```
def max_length_value():
   return 128

class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=max_length_value, unique=True)
```

and in the forms.py

```
from .models import Category

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=max_length_value)
```

Could anybody tell me how to solve this situation ? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Also I will suggest you to refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: Thanks for your advertise, and I read but get no answer about my question. I just try not to repeat the max_length_value in the models.py and forms.py and want to let this value/property can shared by these 2 files. In the tutorial example, all of them are set max_length individually for CharField, and that I know. If max_length has same value for model & form class, how to share for them in one place ?